# Android - To create a test app, is it possible to create a second app instead of a test app?

Tags: android

I am looking to create an app for experiments and testing, but I would like to actually make it a real app instead of a test app so I can test various sorts of things on real users as well.

I am wondering what would be the main difference between a real test app for a current app I have, and another real app that I would use for testing.

Also, how do I actually make a second real app? Is there documentation for how to create a second app under the same account? I am not sure what would be different.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question! I downloaded Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), plugged into Eclipse and created tens of applications till date. What is the restriction of creating just one app? And how is a test app different from actual app?

Comment: @Kamal I am not too sure how a test app is different from another app. I assume it has to at least be restricted to outside users. But I am sort of foggy on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restriction on number of apps you can create using SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Also all your apps are test apps unless you publish then in Android Market, from where users can download your app.

So don't worry, play around with SDK, create as much apps you want, run them in emulator, or on any android phone (set phone in debug mode). And once you feel your app is ready for outside users, just publish the app to the world http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html